# Adding an upload feature blocked my multiple deletion

Tags: php

Multiple deletion used to work just fine before adding the upload page and condition
am sure the problem comes from a  in one of the echo's
I didn't manage to figure out a way to get them both working at the same time.

You can check by yourself here: [agencedevoyages.tk](http://agencedevoyages.tk)

Enter the
email: *abc@gmail.com*

Password: *2*

You'll notice that upload does work and multiple deletion doesn't work anymore

**Code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Accueil</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['email']) AND isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
echo "<b>Welcome ".$_SESSION['prenom']." ".$_SESSION['nom']." !";
echo "<div align='right'><a align='right' href='deconnect.php'><button type='button'>Se déconnecter</button></a></div>";
?>
<table border="1" align="center">
<caption><b><h1>La liste des étudiants</h1></caption>
<tr><td align="center"><b>Photo</td>
<td align="center"><b>Matricule</td>
<td align="center"><b>Nom</td>
<td align="center"><b>Prénom</td>
<td align="center"><b>Adress</td>
<td align="center"><b>Birthday</td>
<td align="center"><b>E-mail</td>
<td align="center" colspan="2"><b>Option</td>
<td align="center"><b>Multiple Deletion</td>
<td align="center"><b>Upload</td></tr>
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM etudiant";
$res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
echo "<tr><td>";
?>
<?php
if(empty($row['photo']))
{
?>
<img src='photos/image.jpg' width="100" height="100">
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<img src='photos/<?php echo $row['photo'] ?>' width="100" height="100">
<?php
}
echo "</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$row['matricule']."</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$row['nom']."</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$row['prenom']."</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$row['adresse']."</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$row['date_naissance']."</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$row['email']."</td>";
if($_SESSION['email']==$row['email'] OR $_SESSION['email']=='abc@gmail.com')
{
echo "<td><a href='modif.php?id=".$row['id']."'><button type='button'>Edit</button></a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='supp.php?id=".$row['id']."'><button type='button'>Delete</button></a></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><form method='post' action='supp3.php'><input type='checkbox' name='sup[]' value='".$row['id']."'></form></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type='file' name='fichier'><input type='submit' value='Confirm'></td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'></td></tr>";
}
}
echo "<tr><td colspan='9'></td><td colspan='1' align='center'><button>Multiple Deletion</button></td></tr></form>";
}
else
{
echo "<tr><td colspan ='10' align='center'>No users.</td></tr>";
$sql = "TRUNCATE etudiant";
$res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
}
?>
</table>
<p align="center"><a href="ajout.php"><button>Add a user</button></a></p>
<?php
}
else
{
echo "<div align='center'><b><h1>Not allowed.";
echo "<br><a href='index.php'><button type='button'>Back</button></a></div>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The button Multiple Deletion execute some action?

Comment: It goes to upload.php , while it used to (as it should) go to supp3.php to execute the deletion

Comment: I tried like 9999 ways to fix that </form> thing, couldn't figure it out bro